# How can I insert all rows from one table into another table with Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables in SQL Server.

Table one contains these columns:

```
1-id
2-name
3-family
4-address
```

and table two contains these columns:

```
1-id
2-name
```

In table one I have 100000 rows and read all record with this query:

```
var query = (from p in datacontext.table1
             select p).toArray();
```

I want insert all data from up query into the table2, now I use this method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < query.count(); i++) {
     table2 beh = new tabl2();
     beh.name = query[0].name;
     datacontext.table2.insertonsubmit(beh);
     datacontext.submitchange();
}
```

Is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do it in database?

Answer (score 1):

Making use of Linq to SQL to insert record one by one will take lot of time. Instead of that I Suggest make use of Bulk insert so that your data get insert in one go in less amount of time for that you can make use of of DataTable and OpenXML. for that tutorial is : [Bulk Insertion of Data Using C# DataTable and SQL server OpenXML function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417181/Bulk-Insertion-of-Data-Using-Csharp-DataTable-and)

or use this

[SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (DataTable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)

Comment: thanks for pay attention to my problem,but how can i use bulk from linq query?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - it not necessary you stick with linq for all problem, you should go with the solution which provide good way to implement with less complexity and faster insert for your problem

Comment: Ok,my data into the table1 and want copy all data two the table2,how can i write that with bulk in the c#?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - just check second link which is more suitable for you ..SqlBulCopy that will have example code also...

Comment: thanks,best tutorial,but how can i select just name column from table1 with your link tutorial and sqlbulkcopy to table2?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table2";
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");

using (var reader = new EntityDataReader<Table1>(query))
{
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
}
```

[EntityDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitydatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using Bulk insert in `System.Data.SqlClient` data get insert in to db in less amount of time using the help of datatable

```
 DataTable dt = getData();
 SqlBulkCopyOptions options = SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default;
                    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconnection, options, null))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(long)).SetOrdinal(0);
                        dt = AddDefaultColumn(dt);
                        sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 300;
                        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tableName";
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    }
```

Comment: i want just insert all name column from table1 to table2,please write that

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088779/fill-datatable-from-linq-query) this link will help you

Comment: i'm write the DataTable dt = query_detail_allrow.CopyToDataTable();,but get error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82447/discussion-between-sanjeev-s-and-behzad-razzaqi).

Comment: var query_detail_allrow = from p in mainbehzad.TAXBILLCRMTEMPs
                                                        select p;
            
            DataTable dt = query_detail_allrow.CopyToDataTable();

Comment: write up code and my error:Error 9 The type 'REPORT_MANAGER.TAXBILLCRMTEMP' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'REPORT_MANAGER.TAXBILLCRMTEMP' to 'System.Data.DataRow'. D:\MASHHAD SOFWARE\ver2\REPORT MANAGER\REPORT MANAGER\TaxCRMBILLLOAD.cs 222 28 REPORT MANAGER

Answer (score -1):

Say your table name is table1 and table2 with the columns of id and description you can use

```
INSERT INTO table2  (id, description)
       SELECT table2.id, table2.description
       FROM table1;
```

furthermore you can add a where

```
INSERT INTO table2  (id, description)
           SELECT table2.id, table2.description
           FROM table1 where table1.id =1;
```

you can visit this link for more info https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: what is where table1.id =1;>>?

Comment: if you want to select only one row from table1 that is the query

Comment: your solution in the sql command,but i want linq to sql command!