# how to insert LINQ results to SQL table? (Specifically where to reference destination table)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Looked at a few examples to insert data(links below) but dont see the syntax to reference the destination table.

Whats the LINQ to SQL version of `INSERT INTO Table2` based on SQL code below?

```
--append to table
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/insert-update-and-delete-operations

Comment: Linq itself is not a database technology. There are implementations that use Linq in coordination with data access - like Linq to SQL and Entity Framework. You will probably prefer Entity Framework for which you should be able to Google plenty of resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert all rows from one table into another table with Linq-to-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238393/how-can-i-insert-all-rows-from-one-table-into-another-table-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @crowcoder, I think I mean Linq to SQL

Comment: @VinhTon, that's fine, but know that Linq to SQL has generally fallen out of favor and all but replaced by Entity Framework. It's a matter of opinion (LINQPad still uses it) but if you are going to learn something, EF is more transferable knowledge.

Comment: @Crowcoder, definitely good to know! LINQPad is my exploration to go beyond SQL so I am concerned if its worth it in the long run. I'll start a separate post to solicit recommendations