# how to get full table in to a var in c# ,mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a data table and i'm filtering data from it. now I want to get full table into var like below

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
dv.RowFilter = "[CRUISE-ONLY]='YES' AND [NOW-AVAIL]='YES' AND [1A] <> 'N/A'";

table = dv.ToTable();

var allneededmsc = (from DataRow dr in table.Rows
                    where (string)dr["CRUISE-ONLY"] == "YES" && 
                    (string)dr["NOW-AVAIL"] == "YES" && 
                    (string)dr["1A"] != "N/A"
                    select (string)dr["aLL COLUMNS"]);
//here I want to select full table which fulfill the conditions.
```

how can I do this.

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17088904/4383585