# Deserializing JSON with an empty value that was serialized as {}

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-core, deserialization

I'm using the Newtonsoft Json Converter to serialize and deserialize objects and it works great for my program.

But if any of the values stored within the object are null/empty, they are serialized as `{}`, unable to be deserialized, and my program stops.

**For example**, if I deserialize the following code, everything works great:

```
{
"Thing1": 2,
"Thing2": false,
"Thing3": "string",
"Thing4": "2017-10-28T14:04:24.74"
}
```

But if I try to deserialize the following code:

```
{
"Thing1": {},
"Thing2": false,
"Thing3": "",
"Thing4": {}
}
```

Thing1 and Thing4 will both cause problems during deserialization.

Not sure if this could be related to the way I am reading from my database to serialize:

```
var r = Serialize(myReader);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, 
                        Formatting.Indented, 
                        new JsonSerializerSettings 
                        { 
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
                        });

public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> Serialize(SqlDataReader reader)
           {
            var results = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            var cols = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                cols.Add(reader.GetName(i));

            while (reader.Read())
                results.Add(SerializeRow(cols, reader));

            return results;
            }

private Dictionary<string, object> SerializeRow(IEnumerable<string> cols,
                                                    SqlDataReader reader)
            {
                var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (var col in cols)
                    result.Add(col, reader[col]);
                return result;
            }
```

I've used:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }
```

Within my deserializer:

```
BlankObject blnkObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlankObject>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

#### How can I deserialize an empty value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What "problems" does it cause and what did your research show for that?

Comment: My program errors out whenever an empty value is deserialized. If I comment out the empty values within the BlankObject class (in this case Thing1 and Thing4), deserialization works. `int Thing1 { get; set; }`

Comment: The problem is that the value of `"Thing1"` is sometimes an integer and sometimes an object of unknown type.  What type should Json.NET when creating a `DataColumn` for such a property?  If you know in advance the correct type for `"Thing1"` you could create your own version of `DataTableConverter` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126529/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a class structure like following:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public object Thing1 { get; set; }
    public bool Thing2 { get; set; }
    public string Thing3 { get; set; }
    public object Thing4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I already figured out my problem, just posted the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem thanks to the comment by @dbc

An object of null value is serialized as `{}` in JSON instead of `null`

The deserializer did not like deserializing `{}` into an int. Because a *null object* is of a different **type** than an *int* or *DateTime*.

My solution was to serialize the results of the database to have `null` instead of `{}` by reading from the database like this:

```
BlankClass test = new BlankClass();
string json = "";

if (myReader.Read())
{
      test.Thing1 = (int)myReader[0];
      test.Thing2 = (bool)myReader[1];
      test.Thing3 = (string)myReader[2];
      test.Thing4 = (Datetime?)myReader[3];
      json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
 }

 class BlankClass
 {
      int Thing1 { get; set; }
      bool Thing2 { get; set; }
      string Thing3 { get; set; }
      DateTime? Thing4 { get; set; }
 }
```