# JSON to Datatable: Error converting Value

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, json.net

I have this JSON, which is valid according to JSONbeautify.com :

```
{
    "date_check": "2023-04-05",
    "updated_datas": [
        {
            "FIELD_NAME": "BLN_ADS_LINKS_DETECTED",
            "NEW_VALUE": false,
            "OLD_VALUE": true
        },
        {
            "FIELD_NAME": "ADS_LINKS_DETECTED",
            "NEW_VALUE": null,
            "OLD_VALUE": "?"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to display it in a datatable.
I use this function:

```
 Public Function JsonStringToDataTable(ByVal json As String) As DataTable
        Dim jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim srcArray = jsonLinq.Descendants().Where(Function(d) TypeOf d Is JArray).First()
        Dim trgArray = New JArray()

        For Each row As JObject In srcArray.Children(Of JObject)()
            Dim cleanRow = New JObject()

            For Each column As JProperty In row.Properties()

                If TypeOf column.Value Is JValue Then                   
                    cleanRow.Add(column.Name, column.Value)
                    End If
            Next

            trgArray.Add(cleanRow)
        Next

        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(trgArray.ToString(), New JsonSerializerSettings With {.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore})
End Function
```

I got this exception:
`Error converting value "?" to type 'System.Boolean'. Path '[1].OLD_VALUE', line 10, position 20.`
I don't understand: why a boolean?

Comment: _"I don't understand: why a boolean?"_ - highly likely that because `[0].OLD_VALUE` is `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET will use the first row to determine the datatype for column, so it will process `OLD_VALUE` as bool for this input json. Since you are already processing json manually you can try forcing all data being strings. Not fluent with VB but here is working snippet in C# to give you the idea (main idea is to use `ToString` on prop value when adding it to the new object - `row.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToString())`, but there is some other stuff also):

```cs
var json = ...; // string from question
var jToken = JObject.Parse(json)["updated_datas"];
var jArray = new JArray();
foreach (var child in jToken.Children<JObject>())
{
    var row = new JObject();
    foreach (var prop in child.Children<JProperty>())
    {
        row.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToString());
    }
    jArray.Add(row);
}

var table = jArray.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Or you can create custom `DataTableConverter` which will infer correct type, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126529/2501279)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to fix json would be to use a string replacement

```
 json = json.Replace("false","\"false\"").Replace("true","\"true\"")
```

also try this instead of your tonns of code

```
Dim dt As DataTable = JObject.Parse(json)("updated_datas").ToObject( Of DataTable)()
```