# LINQ Return null even if it meets condtion

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Not sure why it happen, I observed it in debugging mode and condition inside the LINQ has been meet

```
if (chkSometing.Checked)
{
  var _results = from itemlist in dtResult.AsEnumerable()
                 where itemlist.Field<string>("data_visibility").Contains("both")
                 select itemlist;
  try { dtResult = _results.CopyToDataTable(); }
  catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message); }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill Datatable from linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088779/fill-datatable-from-linq-query)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not the case, Before that query I have successfully convert it to data table. But right now it worked. I change the "Contains" to Equal. Thanks for your time pal

Comment: @RichardMarkBonifacio good work, post your answer for other's future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you may have fixed the problem, I can explain why "Contains" didnt work and "Any" will work in this case.

Contains check if the **sequence** contains an element.

[Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) checks if **any element of sequence** satisfies a condition. Its like a predicate.

So, if you wish to check whether **an element of a sequence** satisfies a condition use "Any". Example below:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "aa", "aaa", "b", "c" };

bool containsBoy = list.Contains("c"); //true
// list.ElementAt(0).Contains("c") // --> Error which is what you are getting

bool anyBoy = list.Any(r => r.Length == 2); // true for "aa"
```

Source:
[What is the difference between Contains and Any in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526773/what-is-the-difference-between-contains-and-any-in-linq/23526778)

Comment: That satisfied me, Thank you for your further, clear and brief explanation. This will help me in future problems

Comment: In the original code that the OP used, do the think the `Contains` call was `String.Contains` or `Enumerable.Contains`? _`Any` only makes sense discussing if the OP's code was using the latter - but I am almost certain it was using the former._